# FreeRTOS MPU: privileged access to bss?

Tags: freertos, usermode, mpu

I am using `FreeRTOS` 10.5.1 with `MPU` support on a `Cortex M4 microcontroller (STM32F4)`.

I created some tasks (all privileged -> `portPRIVILEGE_BIT` set) and my system is running fine.

Now I tested again with one task not having the `portPRIVILEGE_BIT` `set (= User Mode)`.

When entering the task right up in the first function `(HAL_TIM_Base_Start())` I am getting a memory management exception.
The mem manage address register shows an address in the bss (where the timer is located).

Why does the `MPU` trigger when accessing the bss? (I checked the `__privileged_data_end__` ends before)
How does a User Mode task behave when accessing an area (like bss) that is not explicitly configured as e.g. `portMPU_REGION_READ_WRITE in xRegions[]?`

```
Access to bss with portPRIVILEGE_BIT set -> no problem.
Access to bss with portPRIVILEGE_BIT reset -> mem management fault.
```

configured addresses:

```
0x20000000   privileged_data_start 
0x20006000   privileged_data_end 

0x2000AF65   Mem manage address register <- fault location
```

**Edit:**
I did another test and created a MPU region definition for `0x2000A000 to 0x2000F000` to be `portMPU_REGION_READ_WRITE`.

Now the program is running fine for function no.1 in my task, but it's failing in function no.2 -> fault location is now `0x20006498`.

Is it really neccessary for an User mode task to explicitly define all areas that it is allowed to access? Is leaving a memory area undefined not sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everybody with the same issue, I just received the answer from FreeRTOS support:

> Yes, it is necessary to grant an unprivileged task all the accesses
> explicitly. By default, an unprivileged task has only access to its
> stack. The application writer is expected to grant access to required
> memory regions explicitly.